# How do I install systemless SuperSU in Samsung?

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, supersu, systemless-root

I'm currently using a custom Android 6.0 ROM on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N900. I need to put suhide in my device and it need systemless SuperSU to be installed, Google didn't help me at all. Any of you guys know how to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using stock Android 6 and newer you can only have systemless root because of security restriction. So if you root your phone running stock Android 6, you will have systemless root.

Because you are using a Samsung phone it might be a bit more tricky. It could be that your custom rom has it's own su installation in the system partition. Then it's not systemless. To have a systemless root installation it's required to install su in the boot image. This requires your device's bootloader to allow flashing the boot image.

On most devices you can somehow flash the boot image by unlocking the bootloader.

For more information about what systemless root is have a look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/249162/what-is-systemless-root-on-android-and-why-is-it-better/).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the need for a systemless installation of SuperSU is not detected by the installation script, to force this to occur follow the following steps.

1. Start TWRP 3.0 or higher on the device
2. Go to Advanced - Terminal
3. In the terminal, enter `echo SYSTEMLESS=true>>/data/.supersu`
4. Press `Enter`
5. Exit to the TWRP main menu
6. Flash the current SuperSU as per normal

When flashing SuperSU, you should see in the TWRP recovery log screen mentions of system-less installation and patching of the boot image.

Comment: My ROM is currently already rooted. Do I need to unroot before doing all these?

Comment: Guess I am confused... Why do you want systemless root? Some devices require it, others do not... There is no technical advantage of one over the other. But yes, you would have to fully unroot, then do this process. If your on a custom ROM it likely won't work though, have to go back to rom dev, if stock it should provided you are on Marshmallow or newer. Systemless root does not work on older Android versions.

Comment: Welp, ok. Guess I'm not able to install systemless root then. My stock ROM is Android 5.1.1, I just need systemless root to hide root form Pokemon Go lol. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @Yayy Systemless does not hide root from apps... That is done by suhide, rootcloak, or Magisk, but recent changes to SafetyNet (mandatory part of play services) have made it impossible to hide root.

Comment: Wow ok, I'm gonna use my Ipad then :D